# Google map memory usage on VB.Net form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using a Google map inside of vb.net application. The problem is that it keeps taking a memory space whenever I search a map on a web browser which is on a windows form . Even though I close the form, it is not disappeared from memory. The size of memory is just going up. That goes away when I close MDI form. 
What is the solution for this? How do I manage the memory problem?

-->Edited : One of out team member found the solution. It worked out pretty well. Just call the function whenever you want to do it. I used it on Form Closing event.

```
<DllImport("psapi.dll")> _
    Public Function EmptyWorkingSet(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function GetCurrentProcess() As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Sub FreeMemory()
        EmptyWorkingSet(GetCurrentProcess())
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [my answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786000/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-in-c/6786176#6786176) I believe your best bet is to do some profiling.

I ran the trial version of ANTS memory profiler, against an app I was working on and the problem I discovered is outlined in this [walthrough](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough) of how to use the tool (specifically the details around figures 10 - 15).

Basically, I was subscribing to some events on a form, but then not unsubscribing from them when the form was closed. This meant there was still a reference to the form and it (along with all it's controls and members) were never collected.

Maybe you have a similar situation, but your best bet is to look at the code in a profiler. It doesn't have to be this one (this is just the one I've used). It will certainly help you identify the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I will try the way to track the memory leaking. By the way, I will be appreciated if you can comment on the solution that I placed on the question whether it is good solution or not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't comment directly on the solution, but my only suggestion to your edited post, is that it might be worthwhile making your call from Dispose rather than Form Closing. Also, during your debugging, put a breakpoint in Dispose to ensure it is always called.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the liberal garbage collection in .NET.  If you're really concerned about memory, try this.

First, ensure that the objects you wish to remove have been disposed.  If this is a Windows Form, this should be automatic.

Call `System.GC.Collect()`.  You should see your memory usage decrease.

Comment: I tried System.GC.Collect() but it reduces only about 20 % of what it is used. It does not reduce 100% of memory what the form occupied when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you could use an MDI parent and put your maps into MDI child forms opening up a new one each time (or periodically closing unused ones)?